# Warnings in compilation

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to compile a simple program written in c on my new desktop. It installed completely normally without any error on my older machine but for some reason it is giving me lots of compilation warnings when I am trying to compile it here. I installed gcc, g++, xpm and xlib which are the pre requisites of this program. Could it be that I am missing some library or something on my new machine?
Here are the warnings I get:

```
gcc -o view_qsfr qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c -lX11 -lm -lc -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lXpm
In file included from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:44:0:
qsfr_2005a_readQSFR.c: In function ‘Read_QSFR’:
qsfr_2005a_readQSFR.c:706:19: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[201]’ [-Wformat=]
             scanf("%s",&fname_extra);
                   ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c: In function ‘XRotPaintAlignedString’:
rotated.c:450:9: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  return NULL;
         ^
rotated.c:453:36: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     my_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, drawable, NULL, 0);
                                    ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c:510:45: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  depth_one_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, empty_stipple, NULL, 0);
                                             ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c:566:43: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   depth_one_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, new_bitmap, NULL, 0);
                                           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c: In function ‘XRotDrawHorizontalString’:
rotated.c:670:36: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     my_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, drawable, NULL, 0);
                                    ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c: In function ‘XRotCreateTextItem’:
rotated.c:982:36: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     font_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, canvas, NULL, 0);
                                    ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c: In function ‘XRotAddToLinkedList’:
rotated.c:1240:18: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     DEBUG_PRINT4("current cache size=%ld, new item=%ld, limit=%ld\n",
                  ^
rotated.c:66:53: note: in definition of macro ‘DEBUG_PRINT4’
 #define DEBUG_PRINT4(a, b, c, d) if (debug) printf (a, b, c, d)
                                                     ^
rotated.c:1253:15: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
  DEBUG_PRINT2("Removed %d bytes\n", i1->size);
               ^
rotated.c:64:47: note: in definition of macro ‘DEBUG_PRINT2’
 #define DEBUG_PRINT2(a, b) if (debug) printf (a, b)
                                               ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:0:
qsfr_2005a_graphics.c: In function ‘initX’:
qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:48:27: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  gc=XCreateGC(display,win,NULL,NULL);
                           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:0:
qsfr_2005a_graphics.c: In function ‘Plot_Correlation_Matrix’:
qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:748:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XpmWriteFileFromPixmap’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          XpmWriteFileFromPixmap(display, fname_out, pix, 0, NULL);
          ^
qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c: At top level:
qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:413:4: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
    main(int argc, char **argv)
    ^
physics@XPHYS9G7XGC2LLT:~/Desktop/viewQSFR/viewQSFR$ sudo make
gcc -o view_qsfr qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c -lX11 -lm -lc -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lXpm
In file included from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:44:0:
qsfr_2005a_readQSFR.c: In function ‘Read_QSFR’:
qsfr_2005a_readQSFR.c:706:19: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[201]’ [-Wformat=]
             scanf("%s",&fname_extra);
                   ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c: In function ‘XRotPaintAlignedString’:
rotated.c:450:9: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  return NULL;
         ^
rotated.c:453:36: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     my_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, drawable, NULL, 0);
                                    ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c:510:45: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  depth_one_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, empty_stipple, NULL, 0);
                                             ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c:566:43: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   depth_one_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, new_bitmap, NULL, 0);
                                           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c: In function ‘XRotDrawHorizontalString’:
rotated.c:670:36: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     my_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, drawable, NULL, 0);
                                    ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c: In function ‘XRotCreateTextItem’:
rotated.c:982:36: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     font_gc=XCreateGC(dpy, canvas, NULL, 0);
                                    ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:8:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
rotated.c: In function ‘XRotAddToLinkedList’:
rotated.c:1240:18: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     DEBUG_PRINT4("current cache size=%ld, new item=%ld, limit=%ld\n",
                  ^
rotated.c:66:53: note: in definition of macro ‘DEBUG_PRINT4’
 #define DEBUG_PRINT4(a, b, c, d) if (debug) printf (a, b, c, d)
                                                     ^
rotated.c:1253:15: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
  DEBUG_PRINT2("Removed %d bytes\n", i1->size);
               ^
rotated.c:64:47: note: in definition of macro ‘DEBUG_PRINT2’
 #define DEBUG_PRINT2(a, b) if (debug) printf (a, b)
                                               ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:0:
qsfr_2005a_graphics.c: In function ‘initX’:
qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:48:27: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘XCreateGC’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  gc=XCreateGC(display,win,NULL,NULL);
                           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:7:0,
                 from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1584:11: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void *’
 extern GC XCreateGC(
           ^
In file included from qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:45:0:
qsfr_2005a_graphics.c: In function ‘Plot_Correlation_Matrix’:
qsfr_2005a_graphics.c:748:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XpmWriteFileFromPixmap’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          XpmWriteFileFromPixmap(display, fname_out, pix, 0, NULL);
          ^
qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c: At top level:
qsfr_2005a_tool_box.c:413:4: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
    main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Comment: I cant find the errors, because it is full of warnings

Comment: Are you able to do `gcc --version` on both systems for a comparison?

Comment: There is no error in what you provided.. Only warnings.. Can you emphasize the error you are talking about?

Comment: Okay, Yes the warnings. Apologies, may be I am saying it wrong. How do I proceed with the compilation in this case then?

Comment: I don't have my older system now but gcc --version  on the newer one is this: gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413

Comment: Your question is unrelated to make, if you actually have errors then post them, if not then you might want to change your question title.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I don't have errors, I just have these warnings but I am unable to proceed with the code because of these warnings. Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is C, not C++

Comment: You have to `cast` few variable, nothing to worried

Comment: Some versions use `#define NULL 0`, some use `#define NULL ((void *)0)`.  Your new compiler has something similar to the latter, so places where you used to pass zero (`0`) via `NULL` are now passing a pointer instead — hence the warnings about converting from pointer to integer.  The type warning on the `printf()` is because you're passing the address of an array to a function that expects a `char *`.  Remove the `&`.

Comment: @PandaCool: Using the casting-hammer is probably the worst approach to fix those warnings ... :-/

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using the `-Werror` flag to turn warnings into errors then the compiler will still have produced an executable that you can run.

The warnings are probably due to the fact that your new system has a newer compiler that is better at detecting problems in your code.

My suggestion would be to fix the warnings if you can/have time. Otherwise just run the program and ignore the warnings (for now, but fix them eventually).

Comment: Thanks Jesper. I tried doing that but it is not running. I ignored the warnings but now it does not run and core dumped segmentation fault. The problem is, that I am new to c coding. I use python mostly so don't have much idea how to fix these warnings

Comment: Time to fix the warnings then and do some debugging if the warnings don't actually point to the crash bug. But fix the warnings first, they may likely be pointing at your bug.

Comment: Ahh! okay :( Well Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Is your new computer 64 bit? 
Is your older computer 32 bit? 
The types of warnings I see suggest that you have 32 bit code that you might be trying to compile on a 64 bit computer (as well as the compiler being a much newer version).

Comment: Yes Shadowfen, Thats exactly the problem. The older computer was 32 bit.

Comment: Common problems with 32bit C code trying to compile on 64bit: 1. Pointers are not the same size as ints, 2. functions that take varargs (such as scarf and printf) must use the appropriate size of specifier in the format string, and 3. NULL != 0 - particularly important when passing in varargs parameters that expect the last arg to be NULL to denote the end of the arg list.

Comment: Is there a way I can get around this problem without having to change/edit the code much?

Comment: You might take a look at How to compile 32bit on 64bit systems: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compile-32bit-application-using-gcc-64-bit-linux.html

Comment: "*without having to change/edit the code much*" Fixing those apx 40 warnings should not take longer then max. an hour. @LilySharpton